# Oracle10g SQL pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

I have a table named TABLE  for example looking like:

```
ID  | email
--------------
1   |  a@a.com 
1   |  b@b.com
2   |  c@c.com
3   |  d@d.com
3   |  e@e.com
```

and I would like to return something like

```
ID | email1 | email2
--------------------
1  | a@a.com| b@b.com
2  | c@c.com|
3  | d@d.com| e@e.com
```

I was wondering how I could use pivoting to help me get rid of duplicate ID rows and just add an extra column for their other emails. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT id, email1, email2, email3
FROM (
SELECT id, 
        email, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY email) AS emailRank
FROM TABLE
) 
pivot( max(email) FOR emailRank IN (1 as email1, 2 as email2, 3 as email3));
```

Edit: fixed above thanks to beach's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using the GROUP BY solution with CASE expression.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN emailRank = 1 THEN email END) AS [1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN emailRank = 2 THEN email END) AS [2],
    MAX(CASE WHEN emailRank = 3 THEN email END) AS [3],
    MAX(CASE WHEN emailRank = 4 THEN email END) AS [4]
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, 
        email, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY email) AS emailRank
    FROM TABLE
)
GROUP BY id;
```

Original Pivot example had type and missing ")".  Try the following to get pivot working:

```
pivot( max(email) FOR emailRank IN (1,2,3));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works just as I need it. However, when I try using the pivoting method, I end up getting a MISSING expression where [1] AS email1 in the first line... Do you mind explaining what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: added code that I believe will fix OP original pivot query.  Small typo (nax vs max) and missing ")".  Also replaced [1] with 1.

Comment: Sorry about that, those were typos only in my post. However, using those 1, 2,  3 doesn't seem to work. I get a query, but it comes out to be like email1 with 1's, email2 with 2's, etc. It doesn't show the emails like abc@abc.com.

Comment: oh, change your SELECT clause to SELECT * and see what happens.

Comment: got it finally. thank you so much. i had to pivot and just do 1 as email1, 2 as email2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a procedure or a combination of group by rownum and decode. Personally, I find the procedure approach cleaner.

See: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:15151874723724

Comment: I think I need to keep it all in a single SELECT query so I think I might need to do it the combo of group by and decode. Would I group by ID and then use decode for the rest?

Comment: Yeah, you basically use decode to determine what the value of the columns are based on the current row. I think this approach is fine if you don't that many columns.