# Genrate a report in crystal report where count of a field put into a column

Tags: sql, oracle, vb6, crystal-reports

I have to generate a report in Crystal report and VB report where database is Oracle, like the attached screen shot:

[image]

I have used the following query and got the output as below screen shot:

```
SELECT ins.ins, ins.ins_name, crdi.ct, crdi.bin,
(select count(*) from crdh where crd_st='CN') as CNcount, (select count(*) 
from crdh where crd_st='PO') as POcount
FROM crdh, crdi, ins
where crdh.bn=crdi.bn and crdi.ins=ins.ins and crdh.crd_st IN ('PO','CN')
GROUP BY ins.ins, crdi.bn, ins.ins_name,crdi
ORDER BY ins.ins, crdi.bn;
```

[image]

I have the following issues:

1. How can I correct the above query so that it can return the count of crd_st for a perticular bn where crd_st is 'CN' or 'PO' separately. For example this query should tell me what is the count of records where crd_st is PO for bn 123456.
2. I am very new in the Crystal report. Please help to make this report file and
3. Also tell me how can I implement Sr No for numbering of records in this report file(.rpt).

I ran the following query and got the output as below screen shot

```
SELECT ins.ins_name,ins.ins,
crdi.crd_st, crdi.bin, crdh.crd_st, 
COUNT(crdh.crd_st) as count
FROM crdh, crdi, ins
WHERE crdh.crd_st IN ('PO','CN') and crdi.bn in 
(select unique bn from crdh)and crdh.bn=crdi.bn and 
crdi.ins=ins.ins
GROUP BY ins.ins, crdi.bn, ins.ins_name,
crdi.crd_st,crdh.crd_st
ORDER BY ins.ins, crdi.bn;
```

[image]

I want to show the count column as a row in the report for respective bn.

I have Oracle 10g database and followed the following link

[link for pivote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963684/oracle10g-sql-pivot)

And make the following query and got the 'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended' error.

```
SELECT bn, CNCount, POCount
FROM (
SELECT bn, 
    crd_st, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bn ORDER BY crd_st) AS cardRank
FROM cardholder
) 
pivot( count(crd_st) FOR cardRank IN ('CN' as CNCount, 'PO' as POCount));
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Use the Pivot feature in Oracle 11g: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html - Same answer as Siva below, but it is performed at the database level.

Comment: @ Sun W Kim- I have a 10g oracle database. I have followed the following link:                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963684/oracle10g-sql-pivot         but i got the'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended' error. I added my query in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you got some output, now to manuplate that output as required use cross tab in crystal report.

1. Use `bn` in column.
2. Create a formula `@Count` and write just `"Count"` in that formula and use the formula in rows.
3. Use database field `Count` in summarized fields.

Let me know how it goes

Edit--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
1. Drag the crosstab on to report.
2. `Right click` on crosstab and go to `Crosstab expert`
3. There you will find 3 options, `Rows`, `Columns` and `Summarized fileds`
4. place the field what you want in row, place the filed what you want in column and same way place the column for summarized fields
```

Comment: @Siva- 1. bn is already a column. About which query are you talking about? Please explain it in brief.

Comment: I am talking where to take the column in cross tab.. in crosstab there would be option to give column there use `bn`

Comment: @Siva- Thanks for your help. I am very new in crystal report. Can you please tell me how can i implement cross tab in crystal report for my report.

Comment: Sorry Sive it doe not help me.

Comment: didn't you get `count` as row.. what output you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I got the required output by running the following query:

```
SELECT ins.ins_name,ins.ins,crdi.ct, crdi.bn,
      sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'PO', 1, 0)) POCount,
      sum(DECODE(cardh.crd_st, 'CN', 1, 0)) CNCount
FROM crdh, crdi, ins
WHERE crdh.crd_st IN ('PO','CN') and crdi.bn in 
(select unique bn from crdh)and crdh.bn=crdi.bn and 
crdi.ins=ins.ins
GROUP BY ins.ins, crdi.bn, ins.ins_name,crdi.ct
ORDER BY ins.ins, crdi.bn;
```

Comment: Can any one tell me how can i implement the above query in the crystal reports.